# Async with MVC3 and ASP.NET4.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asynchronous

I am using MVC3 and ASP.NET 4.5

As I understand it, even though I am using ASP.NET 4.5, I cannot use the new MS "Await", "Task" Async features. Am I correct? Do I have to still use the old "AsyncController" approach.

Finally, all I am trying to do is "Async" a private method, not the full Action, like what would happen with a "SendMail" method call.

ie.

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

     SendMail(); // Inbuilt Async

     //Copy Document in DB. This is coded by private method in class, but needs to be fired asynchronously
     CopyDocument();

     ViewBag.Message = "Getting documents, Check back soon";


    return View();
    }
```

So how can I async just "CopyDocument()".

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MVC3 does not recognize `Tasks`.

You can get it from MVC4.

**Update:**
Though MVC3 framework doesn't fully support `Task` `async` `await` directly you may use the `Task.Factory` library as you see in @VsevolodGoloviznin's answer.

In this case recommendation would be use `Task.Run` see [Stephen's blog on startnew-is-dangerous](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html) and [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx) for more details

Use below

```
Task.Run(() => CopyDocument());
```

Instead of

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => CopyDocument());
```

Comment: Thank you for this. This is all very new to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use task parallel library

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => CopyDocument());
```

Comment: Interesting. I do not need to pick up the result in the browser. The copied document will be retrieved from a seperate document page. The process just needs to kick off and complete in its own time, and return control back to action, like what would happen with an Async Mail call. Does the above achieve this?

Comment: I think you deserve a point, as you were the first to mention this library. I did give you one, but someone may have downvoted you. Unfortunately I cannot award another point. I did end up using Task.Run(), having read the blogs, hence the award for the answer. So all I can say is a big thank you for pointing so quickly to Task.Factory